# How to delete UINavigationController's space programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I redirect to a page from `UINavigationController`, the destination page shows the contents of the Navigation Bar with more space above than expected. How can I fix this situation?

MainTabController

```swift
import UIKit

final class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let homeVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeScreen())
        let searchVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchScreen())
        let favouriteVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FavouriteScreen())
        
        homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house"), tag: 0)
        searchVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), tag: 1)
        favouriteVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "favourite", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart"), tag: 2)
        setViewControllers([homeVC, searchVC, favouriteVC], animated: true)
    } 
}
```

HomeScreen:

```swift
import UIKit

enum Sections: Int {
    case Home, Favourite, Search
}

protocol HomeScreenInterface: AnyObject {
    func configureVC()
    func configureNavigationBar()
    func configureTableView()
}

final class HomeScreen: UIViewController {
    var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.view = self
        viewModel.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.fetchWordFromCoreData()
    }
}

extension HomeScreen: HomeScreenInterface {
    func configureVC() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }

    func configureTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(WordCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: WordCell.identifier)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func configureNavigationBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Words"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue]
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "plus"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addWord))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchWord))
    }
}

extension HomeScreen: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.getScreenHeight() * 0.05
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.words.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WordCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! WordCell
        cell.setCell(model: viewModel.words[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

extension HomeScreen {
    @objc func addWord() {
        let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CreateScreen())
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func searchWord() {
        let vc = SearchScreen()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

How the view looks currently: [home screen page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zERJi.png)

I tried to delete the safe area in `UINavigationController` but I failed.

Comment: Remove this line "navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true"  from the ConfigureNavigationBar()

Comment: It's default `prefersLargeTitles = true`. If you want to customize it, you have to create a new one on your own.

Comment: navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true When I remove it, the insert icon and search icon remain in the same position @NisarAhmad

Comment: navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true When I remove it, the insert icon and search icon remain in the same position @son

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to remove rootViewController from UINavigationController in the code I wrote before, so extra space was added

```
   window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainTabBarViewController()) //wrong
   window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarViewController() // correct
```